# PC stutters since new processor bought (Ryzen 5900x) on single threaded load

Tags: cpu, performance

My PC was running good, but I wanted an upgrade in multithreaded loads so I bought 5900X, it does indeed render videos much faster, but ever since the upgrade this happens regularlily when I run heavy loads (even single threaded!):

https://streamable.com/oof8a0 (in case link is down: when moving windows or doing anyhting (even moving mouse) there is a stutter for a fraction of a second every few seconds).

On the video I was running a cpu heavy import process in the background.

When I'm not running very heavy loads, it's all good and works great.

Any ideas what could be the cause of this? Is this a faulty CPU?

I'm attaching my sysinfo and screenshot of task manager while the stutter was happening, as you can see there is nothing to even fill one thread to full, but the stutter only happens on cpu heavy tasks. I tested disk heavy and it's fine.

[image: performance]
[image: sysinfo]

Comment: One of the many things that could cause this, is bad or poorly applied (read airpocks) in the thermal paste on your CPU.

Answer (score 5):

Without full specifications of your rig this is quite hard to reliably diagnose. (Power supply, cooler, things like that)

But for Ryzen 5000 specifically there was [this incident](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/agesa-1207-am4-motherboard-roundup), and in your specifications I can see that you are on a very old BIOS version: `2816` from 24-11-2022.
For your motherboard there are much newer versions, and specifically version `4403`, which states:

> "1. Update AMD AM4 AGESA V2 PI 1.2.0.7.
> 2. Fix AMD fTPM issue causes random stuttering.

You can get the latest release [here](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-x570-f-gaming-model/helpdesk_bios/).

Some other steps to help diagnose your issue.

1. If you upgraded only the CPU and not your PSU, check if your PSU can keep up with the heavy load you are putting on it.
2. Since this is only occurring under high loads, how are the temperatures behaving of the chip? Normally when reaching high temperatures you still shouldn't see stuttering like this, rather a slow down, but it is good to exclude overheating as a potential source of trouble.

Comment: His Bios actually is from 2020 (not 2022) so I'd guess you have a full hit here

Comment: @masourek: Have you tried installing this BIOS version ?

Comment: It appears that was it, thank you!